# IOTA API error when making send transaction call with Node.js client library

Tags: iri-legacy-api, node

I made some test codes to send transactions with Node.js client library, and received the below error response. I cannot find the cause of this error. Did this happen to anyone before? And can anyone explain what went wrong here?

```
Error: Request Error: Request too long
    at Object.requestError (/var/iota-node/node_modules/iota.lib.js/lib/errors/requestErrors.js:11:12)
    at makeRequest.prepareResult (/var/iota-node/node_modules/iota.lib.js/lib/utils/makeRequest.js:293:24)
    at exports.XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/var/iota-node/node_modules/iota.lib.js/lib/utils/makeRequest.js:71:25)
    at exports.XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (/var/iota-node/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:591:25)
    at setState (/var/iota-node/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:610:14)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/var/iota-node/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:447:13)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
```

Codes I used to make transactions

```
    const IOTA = require('iota.lib.js');
    const fs=require("fs");

    const iota = new IOTA({ provider: 'http://iota.node.com:14265' })

    var content = fs.readFileSync("site.pdf", "base64");
    const trytes = 'MYADDRESS';
    var messageToSend = {
        'name': 'Test',
        'message': 'test message',
        'file_content': content
    }

    var messageStringified = JSON.stringify(messageToSend);
    var message = iota.utils.toTrytes(messageStringified);
    var tag = iota.utils.toTrytes('testtag');

    const transfers = [
        {
            value: 0,
            address: trytes,
            message: message,
            tag: tag
        }
    ];

    iota.api.sendTransfer(trytes, 3, 14, transfers, (error, success) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
        } else {
            console.log(success)
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you built the request? I assume that some field (for example the tag) is too long and it is not correctly handled in the library, therefore iri will complain about this when it receives the trytes.

Comment: @mihi I added my codes, can you see if you can find any mistakes I might made? thanks

Comment: How big is the file? Or in other words, how many transactions did prepareTransfers make from it?

```
iota.api.prepareTransfers(trytes, transfers, (error, success) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Unable to prepare")
        } else {
            console.log("Prepared" + success.length+" transactions");
        }
    });
```

I tested your code with a fairly small file (16K) against iota.lib.js 0.4.7 and it worked (https://thetangle.org/bundle/PNCHPLXHOFEFDKZDVKKBZBRGGPLCHHJVWJHOTJLWACBGQLFUHPYNXXAZNACVFVIVARTHBB99GQUULEGHY)

Comment: Also make sure that your address is valid (81 characters of A-Z and 9 only)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a client error, because of a large request size. Besides, publishing large files as transactions requires a large amount of Proof-of-Work, which may take time or cause the connection to close depending on remote node settings. It might be a good idea to split file contents into multiple chunks and attach to tangle in a more granular manner.